# Set neural network initial weight values in C++ torch

Tags: torch, libtorch

I was looking for an API to set initial weight values in libtorch. In the python version, (i.e. `pytorch`) one can easily use `torch.nn.functional.weight.data.fill_(xx)` and `torch.nn.functional.bias.data.fill_(xx)`. But, it seems that such an API does not exist in C++ yet. 
I would appreciate any help or comment to achieve such functionality.

Thanks,
Afshin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this solution better than the previous one in which `model` is an object of type `torch::nn::Sequential`:

```
torch::NoGradGuard no_grad;

for (auto &p : model->named_parameters()) {
    std::string y = p.key();
    auto z = p.value(); // note that z is a Tensor, same as &p : layers->parameters

    if (y.compare(2, 6, "weight") == 0)
        z.uniform_(l, u);
    else if (y.compare(2, 4, "bias") == 0)
        z.uniform_(l, u);
}
```

Instead of `uniform_` you can use `normal_`, ... which are available on torch. This solution is not limited to `torch::nn::Linear` layer and can be used foy any layer type.

Answer (score 0):

I developed this function to do that:

```
void set_weights(fc_model &src_net) {

//    torch::NoGradGuard no_grad;
    torch::autograd::GradMode::set_enabled(false);
    for (int k=0; k < src_net.no_layers-1; k++ ) {
        src_net.layers[k]->weight.uniform_(0.001, 0.001);
        src_net.layers[k]->bias.uniform_(0.0, 0.0);
    }
    torch::autograd::GradMode::set_enabled(true);
}
```

in which `src_net` is a `nn` object which all its layers are gathered in a list, name `layers'.